# Devise redirecting after errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise

On the sign up and forgot password views in Devise, if you get an error, it redirects you to the parent page.

So on the sign up page (`/users/sign_up`), if you get an error, it redirects you to /users and shows the error.

On the forgot password page (`/users/password/new`), if you get an error, it redirects you to `/users/password` and shows the error.

How can I change it so it does the same thing as the sign in page, if there's an error, it stays on the same page and shows the error.

I've looked through Devise and can't find where the redirect is.

Here's my routes for Devise:

```
devise_for :users, :skip => [:sessions]
as :user do
  get 'signin' => 'devise/sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
  post 'signin' => 'devise/sessions#create', :as => :user_session
  get 'signup' => 'devise/registrations#new', :as => :new_user
  post 'signup' => 'devise/registrations#create', :as => :create_user_session
  delete 'signout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
  get "/account" => "devise/registrations#edit"
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is that you have the `post 'signup'` named incorrectly.  What path does your user signup form `POST` to?

```
post 'signup' => 'devise/registrations#create', :as => :create_user_session
```

Should be:

```
post 'signup' => 'devise/registrations#create', :as => :user_registration
```

Here's a look at my `routes.rb` which solved this issue:

```
as :user do
  get "/signin" => "devise/sessions#new", :as => :new_user_session
  post "/signin" => "devise/sessions#create", :as => :user_session
  delete "/signout" => "devise/sessions#destroy", :as => :destroy_user_session
  get "/signup" => "devise/registrations#new", :as => :new_user_registration
  post '/signup' => 'devise/registrations#create', :as => :user_registration
end
```

Answer (score -2):

It doesn't redirect you anywhere, those are the URLs that Devise posts to.

If you want to edit these URLs, see the wiki for a good starting point:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes

Comment: If you go to the sign up page (/users/sign_up) and click sign up without adding any information, you get redirected to /users.

Comment: I just want it to be /signup and if there are any errors, to show up on that page.

Comment: No. `/users` is the path the form posts to. See https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb.

Comment: Oh, I see. How can I change that to same URL?

Comment: see the update to my question. I've already changed them but it still does the same thing

Comment: It doesn't do it for the `sign_in` page though.

Comment: Your `post 'signup'` route name is completely incorrect, and it works for signin because you've skipped the sessions controller when defining your Devise routes. If you want it to work for signup and anything else, you need to exclude those too.

Comment: I've read the wiki but I can't see anything to do with signing up. I'm sorry, I'm knew to Rails.

Comment: You excluded the Sessions controller from the Devise routes, and it now does what you want. How do you think you can make the Registrations controller do the same thing?

Comment: I'm confused. The routes above are in my routes file, I included the new and create action for Sessions and the same for the registrations so why isn't it working? What part did I miss?

Comment: You *excluded the Sessions controller from the Devise routes, and it now does what you want*.

Comment: OH! I see. So would `devise_for :users, :skip => [:sessions], :skip => [:registrations]` be correct?

Comment: It's still doing it though? Also, it didn't do it on the sign_in page even before I included `:skip => [:sessions]`