# Redirect to root_path after failed Devise user registration

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise

I've read & attempted the solutions posted in numerous SO posts (i.e. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11018335/devise-redirect-after-users-fail-signin), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832631/devise-redirect-after-login-fail), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15863354/devise-redirecting-after-errors)) as well as Devise's answer on [how to change the path after a failed registration](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-when-the-user-can-not-be-authenticated), and Devise's [RegistrationsController code](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb), all to no avail.

Instead of doing the custom failure method in the `/lib/` folder like most suggest, It seems like the easiest place to fix/override this would be in the `RegistrationsController#create` method at the bottom where it's:

```
else
  clean_up_passwords resource
  respond_with resource
end
```

It's (I assume) correctly responding with the `user` (i.e. redirecting them to `root_path/users`), but here's the tricky part: I create a nested model when my user registers, and that was quite difficult hacking into Devise for that. I'm afraid that if I go messing with the `RegistrationsController#create` method, that I'll break my perfectly-working nested models.

Someone also mentioned that the Devise solution didn't work for them, but then got it to work after changing a routing problem. I doubt that's the case with me, but here's my `routes.rb` file just in case:

```
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }
  resources :users

  resources :users do
    resources :lockers
  end

  resources :lockers do
    resources :products
  end

  resources :products
  resources :lockups

  match '/user/:id', :to => 'users#show', :as => :user

  root :to => 'home#index'
```

I completely appreciate any help anyone can provide me. I'm still pretty new to Rails, but I'm always happy to learn.

**EDIT:** Thanks to Passionate, I've been trying to figure out how to change the logic in the final `else` block in the registrations controller. Here's what I've tried (along with my noob logic):

```
  # Obviously cleared all the fields since it made no mention of resource
  # redirect_to root_path

  # Too many arguments since root_path takes 0
  # redirect_to root_path resource

  # Just bombed, something about a String somethingorother
  # render root_path

  # Heh, apparently call 'respond_with' and 'redirect_to' multiple times in one action
  # respond_with resource
  # redirect_to root_path
```

Comment: can you please try to be more verbose .  why don't you override the `else` block of `devise/registrations`  . what problem you're facing ?

Comment: @Passionate I could try, but my nearly ten hours of attempts at trying to override the `RegistrationController#create` method, I managed to screw it up every time. I don't understand Ruby's inheritance/overriding well enough to even know what to attempt without risking screwing up my functional registration already.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to fix `routes.rb` file . Since you're using custom controller , you also have to customize `devise_scope` block . Change

```
get "signup", :to => "devise/registrations#new"
```

to

```
get "signup", :to => "registrations#new"
```

And, if you try to override the method and want to set the `root_path` after devise rails registration, you can do like

```
# app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb 
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
   def create
     build_resource
     // The `build_resource` will build the users . 
    if resource.save
     if resource.active_for_authentication?
      set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_navigational_format?
      sign_up(resource_name, resource)
      respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
     else
      set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_navigational_format?
      expire_session_data_after_sign_in!
      respond_with resource, :location => after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
     end
    else

     clean_up_passwords resource
     ## replace your logic here
     redirect_to root_path
    end
   end
end
```

Please note that the above code works with `devise 2.2.4` . Currently, the code which is on master branch on github is changed somewhat due to rails 4 and strong_parameter compatibility .

Comment: Glad to see I'm on the right track, because the part you mentioned `## replace your logic here` is what I've spent quite a while trying to figure out. My signup form is on my home page, and I just want to redirect them back to the home page on unsuccessful registration. I've added everything I've tried to my question.

Comment: @KyleCarlson , please check http://shrouded-meadow-3520.herokuapp.com/ i have created specially for you, might it will be helpful for you .