# Devise redirects to wrong path after failed registration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I set up Devise for my Rails App and everything is working fine so far. The only problem I have is that Devise redirects to a wrong path after a failed registration.

This is how the error looks like when testing:

```
Failures:

1) Register with wrong credentials
   Failure/Error: expect(page.current_path).to eq new_user_registration_path

   expected: "/register"
        got: "/"
```

My test looks like this:

```
feature 'Register' do
   scenario 'with wrong credentials' do
      visit new_user_registration_path
      fill_in 'First Name', with: ''
      fill_in 'Email', with: ''
      fill_in 'Password', with: ''
      fill_in 'Confirm Password', with: '...'
      click_on 'Register'

      expect(page.current_path).to eq new_user_registration_path
      expect(page).to have_content 'errors'
   end
end
```

And here are my routes:

```
devise_for :users,
           path: '/', 
           path_names: { sign_in: 'log_in', sign_out: 'log_out', sign_up: 'register'},
           controllers: { registrations: 'registrations'}
```

I tried to overwrite `devise/registrations#create` like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16766849/redirect-to-root-path-after-failed-devise-user-registration), but ended up loosing the default error-flash message:

```
def create
   build_resource(sign_up_params)
   resource.save

   yield resource if block_given?
   if resource.persisted?
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
         set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_flashing_format?
         sign_up(resource_name, resource)
         respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
         set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_flashing_format?
         expire_data_after_sign_in!
         respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
   else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      # instead of
      # respond_with resources
      # I wrote: 
      redirect_to new_user_registration_path
   end
end
```

I'm using: `Ruby 2.2.0`, `Rails 4.2.0` and `Devise 3.4.1`.

Answer (score 0):

try to change

```
devise_for :users,
           path: '/', 
           path_names: { sign_in: 'log_in', sign_out: 'log_out', sign_up: 'register'},
           controllers: { registrations: 'registrations'}
```

to

```
devise_for :users,
               path: '', 
               path_names: { sign_in: 'log_in', sign_out: 'log_out', sign_up: 'register'}
```

notice I removed the `controllers: { registrations: 'registrations'}` and `'/'`

I think that `path: '/'` is causing the problem

Comment: I changed `path: '/'` as you suggested, but I cannot remove `controllers: { registrations: 'registrations'}`, because I'm rewriting some other stuff in the `registrations_controller`. The error is still there.